# How to detect completion of all contained Observables in Observable<Observable<Object>>

Tags: java, system.reactive, rx-java

I want a method on my api to return Observable<Observable<Object>> but I want the code in that method to know once all contained Observables have completed so that it can close something. What is the best way to do this?

To be more explicit, I'm after this method to be completed:

```
public static <T> Observable<Observable<T>> doWhenAllComplete(
        final Observable<Observable<T>> original, Action0 action) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: show us more code to understand your problem better

Comment: It really depends on how your API method is creating the contained observables.  Can you post some code from your method that produces the `Observable<Observable<Object>>`?  Then we'll know where those inner observables are coming from and the best way for the method to track their completion.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies that my answer is in .NET (as is the system.reactive tag); I am sure you can translate it though!

If your `IObservable<IObservable<Object>>` is given by `source` then:

```
source.Merge()
      .Subscribe(_  => {}, /* not interested in onNext */
                 () => /* onCompleted action here, called when all complete */);
```

Note: This will break down if any of the streams error (causing the merged stream to terminate at that point), so you can also do this to swallow errors on the individual streams:

```
source.SelectMany(x => x.Catch(Observable.Empty<Object>()))
      .Subscribe(_  => {}, /* not interested in onNext */
                 () => /* onCompleted action here, called when all complete */);
```

Comment: You make the assumption that the Observable<Observable<Object>> can be merged without losing meaning. This assumption cannot be made unfortunately.

Comment: Treating your answer as a hint though I think the merge method will be the key to getting there

Comment: I made no such assumption - you only asked to know when all the streams had completed, so that's what I gave you. It sounds like perhaps you have some extra information to add to your question? A great thing to do would be to add a test or tests that the solution should pass. Looking at what you have added, why do you need to pass through the source? Would two separate subscriptions not do it? It would also avoid side-effects.

Comment: I understand, two subscriptions would do it but would spoil encapsulation which I think is achieved in my answer below. Yep I agree you didn't make that assumption thanks. I perhaps needed to make clear that I wanted the action to occur without side effect on the source (beyond the action itself). Your answer led me to my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation of the method seems to do the trick without side effects I believe:

```
public static <T> Observable<Observable<T>> doWhenAllComplete(
        final Observable<Observable<T>> original, final Action0 action) {
    return Observable.create(new OnSubscribeFunc<Observable<T>>() {

        @Override
        public Subscription onSubscribe(Observer<? super Observable<T>> o) {
            ConnectableObservable<Observable<T>> published = original
                    .publish();
            Subscription sub1 = Observable.merge(published)
                    .doOnCompleted(action).subscribe();
            Subscription sub2 = published.subscribe(o);
            Subscription sub3 = published.connect();
            return Subscriptions.from(sub1, sub2, sub3);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works:

```
bothSources = source1.Cast<Object>().Merge (source2.Cast<Object>());
```

In my case, I only needed to wait for 2 sources, but you could create a function that receives a list of sources and merges all of them.